# How do you target div last-child within another div?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I cannot work out how to target div last-child within another div? For this particular project I need it to be structured like that. Is it even possible?

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u713nw51/

HTML

```
<article class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Text</div>
</article>

<article class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Text</div>
</article>

<article class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Text</div>
</article>
```

CSS

```
article { padding-bottom: 20px; }
.inner:last-child { border-bottom: 1px solid #000; }
.inner:last-child { none; }
```

Comment: Solved: https://jsfiddle.net/u713nw51/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this css

```
article:last-child .inner { border-bottom: 1px solid #000; }
```

Because `.inner` is last-child of every article so the css will reflect on all `.inner`. You need to target `.inner` in last article.